# Sleeping after every 5-10 second

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I have a Dell Latitude E7250 laptop and I recently installed Ubuntu but it goes into sleep after 10 seconds at Max all sleep settings are disabled , I have just been able to make it so that it not asking password every time to wake from sleep but laptop is unusable in current state i have to long press power button and then it opens for 10 seconds and goes back to sleep
It could be a driver problem but I am really not sure please help me

Comment: Is it doing that both while being pluged or not ?

Comment: I do not think it is going to sleep it is more likely crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In your system parameters, you should navigate to the "Energy" section and turn off "Black screen" and "Sleep"

Comment: OP states in question all settings disabled.